# Thymeleaf th:field not submitting any value to controller

Tags: spring

Heyho,

im having a little issue with Thymeleaf and eventhough i consulted quite a lot of similar questions i have not found the issue.

Im new to Spring and basically all i want to do is to submit some data over a form and then save it in a DB.This are my controllers

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAllCustomers(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
        return "DisplayCustomerAll";
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute Customer customer) {
        Repository.save(customer);
        return "DisplayCustomerAll";
    }
```

My entity looks like this:

```java
   @Entity
   public class Customer {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        private String firstName;
    
        private String lastName;
    
    
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
    
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
    
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            firstName = firstName;
        }
    
        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            lastName = lastName;
        }
    }
```

and the html as following:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Title</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <header th:insert="fragments/navbar.html :: navbar"> </header>
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> First Name </th>
        <th> Last Name </th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr th:each="customer1 : ${customers}">
        <td><span th:text="${customer1.firstName}"> Title </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${customer1.lastName}"> Author </span></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <form th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${customer}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" >
        <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" >
      <input type="submit" value="Create User">
    </form>
    
    <p th:text="${customer.firstName}" > </p>
    <p th:text="${customer.getFirstName()}" > </p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

i went through quite some guides and tried out a lot, but somewhat customer always stays null. If someone could help i would really appreciate it

Comment: Your code is wrong. `firstName = firstName;` this will assign the value to itself. What you wanted to write was probably `this.firstName = firstName;`. Applies to your other setters as well.

Comment: ahhh as always solutions are that easy, thanks a lot!

Comment: the same happens with `lastName`